# emulating permission access for apps

Tags: applications, permissions

While installing apps in Android, it asks for lots of permission to run.

Sometimes I just want to check out how a app is and not interested in sharing any info with the app.

Is it possible to install a app in a "jail" kind of environment and just emulate whatever permission it ask for and not actually sharing it ??

I hope the question is clear..it may not be exactly what I am asking for ..but if there is any way to accomplish this, let me know.

Thanks!

PS:

Not related with any specific version..although I have JellyBean.

Comment: For a starter, please take a look into our [permissions tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/permissions/info). Whether what you want is possible or not a.o. depends on whether your device is rooted, and what permissions you want to block.

Answer (score 1):

You should try out [XPrivacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy) or [Protect My Privacy](http://repo.xposed.info/module/org.synergylabs.pmpandroid). Both of them require the [Xposed](http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer) framework

Jellybean comes with an in-built hidden permission controller called *App Ops* which is accessible by using [AppOps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.slvn.appops&hl=en) (open source)